# Workflow in Orchard CMS

Tags: content-management-system, workflow, orchardcms, document-management

Does Orchard CMS provide modules for workflow and Document Management??

I have searched the workflow and document management modules in Orchard gallery but couldn't find one.

Can anybody help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about document management, but the new version of Orchard (1.7, I believe slated for this week) is the first to have the Workflows module.

If you install 1.6.1 (latest stable,) it won't have it. However, if you [enlist the 1.x branch](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), you can use the Workflows module. It's relatively stable from what I can tell, but it will be officially stable once version 1.7 is the new default.

Comment: For document management: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Search?packageType=Modules&searchTerm=document